# image relative path in angular2

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I'm working on an Angular2 (MEAN stack) project and I'm trying to add an image (retrieved from a database) in this way:

```
<img [src]="'../../../public/img/mountains-thumbnail/' + mountain.image">
```

mountain.image is a variable that holds the data (the image) retrieved from the database.
App is working but it gives me this error in Google Chrome console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/public/img/mountains-thumbnail/everest.png 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see I can successfully retrieve the image from the database but it seems I have an error on the image path.

Here is my project structure (uppercase is for folders, lowercase is for files):

```
-ASSETS
    - APP
        - MOUNTAINS
              mountain.component.js  // here I'm trying to include the image
-BIN
-MODELS
-NODE_MODULES
-PUBLIC
   - IMG
       -MOUNTAINS-THUMBNAIL
          everest.png
-ROUTES
-VIEWS
app.js
gulpfile.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: try to use single variable which holds your full path to the image. may help you like this : `<img [src]='VariablePath'>` ,  also your folder name is in capital correct it

Comment: folder's names are in uppercase only here, for keeping things clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
<img [src]="'public/img/mountains-thumbnail/' + mountain.image">
```

if your root folder is src or app than use

```
<img [src]="'src/public/img/mountains-thumbnail/' + mountain.image">
```

instead of this one -

```
<img [src]="'../../../public/img/mountains-thumbnail/' + mountain.image">
```

just remove `../../../`

Comment: but same works for me, amazing, have you any root folder ?

Comment: I have a "mountain" folder, inside of it there is the structure I've written in the question. I've also tried with:  "'mountain/public/img/mountains-thumbnail/' + mountain.image"

Answer (score 0):

if you tried @Pardeep Jain answer and did not work with you. 
I can only think that your server cant access the image folder.

verify that your server allowed to access and serve the image folder and image files.